# Why only works the first video call on Android SDK QuickBlox 3.3.1?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app that include a service of video chat (using the **QuickBlox's SDK**). All is fine on the first received call, but after of hang up the video call, the device can't received more calls.

The only suspicious message error is:

> E/class com.xxxx.xxxx.services.CallService: Ping chat server failed

Also `webrtc.Logging` detect the second and more incoming calls, but not show the incoming call fragment.

I'm using **QuickBlox SDK version 3.3.1**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **WebRtcSessionManager** then you need to reset the Session on call disconnect.

```
 public class SessionManager extends QBRTCClientSessionCallbacksImpl {
    private static SessionManager instance;
    private Context context;

    private static QBRTCSession currentSession;
    private SessionManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static SessionManager getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new SessionManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public QBRTCSession getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void setCurrentSession(QBRTCSession qbCurrentSession) {
        currentSession = qbCurrentSession;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewSession(QBRTCSession session) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceiveNewSession to SessionManager");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSessionClosed(QBRTCSession session) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSessionClosed SessionManager");
        if (session.equals(getCurrentSession())){
            setCurrentSession(null);
        }
    }
}
```

If you getting ping error i.e server is not responding .Try to Ping Manually and validate the error codes.

```
 QBPingManager pingManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getPingManager();
    pingManager.pingServer(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }
        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
        // Validate the error code here
        }
    });
```

If you are still getting the issue . I think you are missing something in configuration. Set config as below.

```
QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder chatServiceConfigurationBuilder=buildChatConfigs();
    QBChatService.setConfigurationBuilder(chatServiceConfigurationBuilder);
```

Build config method is.

```
 public static QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder buildChatConfigs() {
    QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new QBChatService.ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setSocketTimeout(60);
        configurationBuilder.setUseTls(true);
        configurationBuilder.setKeepAlive(true);
        configurationBuilder.setAutojoinEnabled(true);
        configurationBuilder.setAutoMarkDelivered(false);
        configurationBuilder.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
        configurationBuilder.setAllowListenNetwork(true);
    return configurationBuilder;
}
```

Comment: I tried but Still i get the same issue, even  after manually ping qb manager.

Comment: I think you are missing configuration .add your configuration here or see my updated answer.

Comment: I am using correct Configuration as you wrote above but still getting same issue.                                                                                                                                   My Log Detail is                                                                                                            ChatPingAlarmManager: onError Server is unavailable
11-28 16:07:07.011 20652-20652/com.chmc E/CallService: Ping chat server failed